# TYPO3 v9 Scheduler does not persist the data

Tags: typo3, task, scheduler, typo3-9.x

I have a function that loads data from a JSON file and enters it into the TYPO3 database. If I call this function via the backend Controller (`indexAction`), then everything works fine. However, when I call it from a task, the data is not saved. By means of test output I see that the object was changed correctly, only the `Update` or `Add` is not executed correctly, because the data in the database is not changed.

Here is my controller function:

```
class ImportController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
{
    protected $siteRepository = null;

    public function injectSiteRepository(SiteRepository $siteRepository)
    {
        $this->siteRepository = $siteRepository;
    }

public function indexAction()
{ 
    $this->dataImport();
}

public function dataImport() {
        $file = "test.json";
        $json = file_get_contents($file);
        $jsonarray = json_decode($json);

        foreach ($jsonarray->{'sites'} as $site) {
            $newValue = false;
            $dbSite = $this->siteRepository->getSiteByID($site->{'ID'});
            if (empty($dbSite->getFirst())) {
                $dbSite = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('test\test123\Domain\Model\Site');
                $dbSite->setID($site->{'ID'});
                $newValue = true;
            } else {
                $dbSite = $dbSite->getFirst();
            }

            //Set Data
            $dbSite->setTest($site->{'TEST'});

            //This object is correct, even in the Task
            DebuggerUtility::var_dump(
                 $dbSite
            );

            //Update or Add new Data
            if (!$newValue) {
                $this->siteRepository->update($dbSite);
            } else {
                $this->siteRepository->add($dbSite);
            }
        }
        $persistenceManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager');
        $persistenceManager->persistAll();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is my task:

```
class JsonImportTask extends AbstractTask {
    public function execute() {
        $objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
            ObjectManager::class
        );
        $controller = $objectManager->get(ImportController::class);
        $controller->dataImport();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Here my repository:

```
public function getSiteByID($id) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->matching(
        $query->equals("uid", $id),
    );
    return $query->execute();
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found my mistake myself. Here is the solution for all who have the same problem:

I added `setRespectStoragePage` in my `getSiteByID` function in SiteRepository:

```
$query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(false);
```

The error was that it was looking for the data at `StoragePid` 1. With this command he searches at the right place

Here is my correct repository function:

```
public function getSiteByID($id) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(false);
    $query->matching(
        $query->equals("uid", $id),
    );
    return $query->execute();
}
```

I had another problem. You have to set the PID number for new entries.

For example, my data is stored on Page ID 12.

I added this line here:

```
if (empty($dbSite->getFirst())) {
    $dbSite = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('test\test123\Domain\Model\Site');
    $dbSite->setID($site->{'ID'});
    $newValue = true;
    $dbSite->setPid(12); //New Line set PID (For me to PID 12)
} else {
    $dbSite = $dbSite->getFirst();
}
```